# Php image post into image field scripting

Tags: php, image, upload, field

I'm struggling on letting the user upload and image to an image field on the HTML doc. When i test it, i can select which image to upload and then click "UPLOAD" but it doesn't go anywhere or go to the field i want to designate it to.

```
 <input name="imgfield" type="image" width="100" height="100">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<p>
<label for="file">Select Picture</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="btn_uploadpic" id="btn_uploadpic" value="UPLOAD" 
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_uplaodpic']))
{
    $id=$_POST['imgfield'];
}   
?>/>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you checking the $_FILES variable. Data regarding your upload should appear in $_FILES['file']

Answer (score 0):

When uploading a file, you won't get the uploaded file in $_POST, but in $_FILES. Check here for a quite detailed example on how to upload files with PHP:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to a temporary filename, using files, you can do something like

```
$_FILES['imgfield']['tmp_name']; // temp_name can be anything
```

If referring to 'name' isn't enough then give the input an 'id' of value 'imgfield'